# Check OpenSSL version in Android with Java runtime or shell command

Tags: shell, command-line, java

I have a problem with checking OpenSSL version in Android device. I've tried to `grep OpenSSL` from `system/lib/libssl.so` with java `runtime.exec`, but it doesn't work?

Anyone can help me, how to make a command to check OpenSSL version in Android?

Answer (score 2):

`grep` doesn't really like binary files, but you can extract the strings from the binary and grep those using `strings`. This binary is not available on most stock ROMs, but you can use Busybox or a similar tool to use it on most devices.

On my device the following command lists the correct OpenSSL version used by libssl.so:

```
strings /system/lib/libssl.so | grep -i openssl
```

This gives me the following output:

```
OpenSSLDie
OPENSSL_cleanse
OPENSSL_DIR_read
OPENSSL_DIR_end
external/openssl/ssl/bio_ssl.c
external/openssl/ssl/d1_both.c
external/openssl/ssl/d1_enc.c
external/openssl/ssl/d1_lib.c
external/openssl/ssl/d1_pkt.c
external/openssl/ssl/d1_srtp.c
external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c
external/openssl/ssl/s23_lib.c
external/openssl/ssl/s23_srvr.c
external/openssl/ssl/s2_clnt.c
external/openssl/ssl/s2_enc.c
external/openssl/ssl/s2_lib.c
external/openssl/ssl/s2_pkt.c
external/openssl/ssl/s2_srvr.c
external/openssl/ssl/s3_both.c
external/openssl/ssl/s3_cbc.c
external/openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c
external/openssl/ssl/s3_enc.c
external/openssl/ssl/s3_lib.c
external/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c
external/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c
external/openssl/ssl/ssl_asn1.c
external/openssl/ssl/ssl_cert.c
OPENSSL_DIR_read(&ctx, '
external/openssl/ssl/ssl_ciph.c
OPENSSL_malloc Error
OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
external/openssl/ssl/ssl_lib.c
external/openssl/ssl/ssl_rsa.c
external/openssl/ssl/ssl_sess.c
external/openssl/ssl/ssl_txt.c
external/openssl/ssl/t1_enc.c
external/openssl/ssl/t1_lib.c
external/openssl/ssl/t1_reneg.c
external/openssl/ssl/tls_srp.c
DTLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
SSLv2 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
SSLv3 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
TLSv1 part of OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
```

I can't confirm that this works for every device, but I see no reason why this would fail.

Comment: +1, although the command wouldn't work on an ordinary ROM. `strings` binary is not included in a typical stock ROM. You would need Busybox for that.

Comment: @Firelord sorry, I did not know that. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @gertmenkel , how to check it if i unroot user? with shell command java runtime?

Comment: @Erwin Sitorus questions about writing apps (on Android or in general) should be asked over at http://stackoverflow.com/. This site is intended for Android users, not Android programmers.

Comment: @gertmenkel, i just wanna checking it if i unroot user with shell comand, because busy box only running if i root user.

Comment: @Erwin Sitorus there is this answer at StackOverflow that discusses many ways to detect if a device is rooted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8097801/3746429

Comment: @gertmenkel, i just want, my coding(shell command with runtime) can running in all android without rooted device, any suggestion how to cek openssl version in android without root?

Comment: @gertmenkel , can you help me to check version of openssl application  from system/app or appplication installed on android ? with grep